# What particle to use as *of* when saying "X percent *of* something"?

Tags: particles

I would like to be able to say X percent of something, but I haven't been able to find the particle that would correspond to *of*. Could you use の？

For example:

> 人口の10パーセント　(10 percent of population)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think you can say の here:

> 人口の１０％
>   *10% of the population*

I think it would be more common to write ％ than パーセント, but either way.

As an aside, for even tenths I think you can use 割 instead:

> 人口の一割
>   *a tenth of the population*

Each 割 is one tenth.